# Apply a function to each line of a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I have a regular expression that I want to apply to each line of a CSV file.

Here's the function which basically removes all comma's encountered before a single digit number. The *function is working perfectly fine* for the string.

```
Input : text = "52A, XYZ Street, ABC District, 2, M, Brown
Function : re.sub('(?<!\s[\dA-Z]),(?!\s+\d,?)', '', text)
Output : '52A XYZ Street ABC District, 2, M, Brown'
```

However, I have a CSV file containing hundreds of such lines. For instance

```
1, 5273249, 1061/72, 150-CF, S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Husband, 9213
1, 5272849, 1063/36, 150-AS, S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Wife, 9253
1, 5274549, 10626/12, 150-RT, S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Son, 9214
```

I tried to read it using CSV reader and apply the function but unfortunately, it's not producing any output. What did I do wrong here:

```
def myFunction(text):
    return re.sub('(?<!\s[\dA-Z]),(?!\s+\d,?)', '', text)

import csv
with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        l = ','.join(row)    
        myFunction(l)
```

Comment: what output do you expect ? nothing is printed or written in a file in this code

Comment: Does `myFunction` return anything? If so, the first thing you should do is assign it to a variable or else the output would be lost.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yes, myFunction is returning the correct output as a standalone function. But not when I'm calling it inside the read CSV method. For some reason the output is getting lost.

Comment: @PRMoureu I expect the commas to get removed before the second occurence of 1 right after S/0:XYZ

Comment: @RohitGirdhar I'm not following your comment. If your function *is returning* the output, why are you not storing it somewhere? Or at the very least, consuming it.

Comment: ok you've been clear enough with the goal in your post, but what kind of output do you need exactly ? print in a shell or written in a file ? you only execute the `myFunction` without handling the returned values

Comment: @PRMoureu I need to write back to the same file I'm reading from.

Comment: @MatiasCicero You are correct. Storing it in a variable does get me the output. But I didn't quite get why if I don't store it in a var, does it not return the output, even though I am using the return statement,

Comment: @RohitGirdhar It was always returning the value, but if you don't handle it in any way it'd just be lost on the void. The output won't get written on a file by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handy module called [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) that allows you to easily edit files line by line.

Take a look at:

```
import re
import fileinput

# For each line
for line in fileinput.input(files='example.csv', inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    # Replace it with the regex you provided
    print(re.sub('(?<!\s[\dA-Z]),(?!\s+\d,?)', '', line), end='')
```

Output:

```
Before:
1,  5273249, 1061/72, 150-CF, S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Husband, 9213
1,  5272849, 1063/36, 150-AS, S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Wife, 9253
1,  5274549, 10626/12, 150-RT, S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Son, 9214

After:
1,  5273249, 1061/72, 150-CF S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Husband, 9213
1,  5272849, 1063/36, 150-AS S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Wife, 9253
1,  5274549, 10626/12, 150-RT S/O:XVZ, 1, ABX, 45, 0, Son, 9214
```

This also creates a handy `example.csv.bak` file for you in case you need it!

Comment: Never heard of file input before, but it does the job perfectly. This saved me a lot of time. Appreciate your help!

Comment: This is **not relevant to the problem**. The example *only incidentally* showed a fix, by `print`ing values rather than `return`ing them. However, it would usually be better to *accumulate* values from each function call. I added duplicate links to the question to show these techniques.